# android: how to debug UI

Tags: android, debugging, user-interface

I am new to android technology, while developing application i need to debug the UI component like why this textview is not displayed or so.
Like we have Log facility for the java code, do we have similar kind of thing for xml also.
so that we can verify which layout is overlapping with another or find out other distortion in UI

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have one. A very basic one. The problem is, the 'debugger' doesn't know what you want. Your `TextView` doesn't display is a problem for you because you want it to display. But the debugger though  you left the code like this simply because you will  programmatically add the text during run time. So debugger for UI wouldn't solve these kind of problems , but it will give you tips and warnings like this : [image]

Comment: Do we have a tool that can give us graphical representation of scenario like TextViewA is over TextViewB. So that from there we can infer, Why TextViewB is not shown.

Comment: Gui editors are great. But they have their limits. I started out with the gui editor too, but very soon I switch to just using pure XML because it has everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, there is a helpful tool to see your UI hierarchy. When in debug mode, open the "Devices" window (if you can't find it: Alt+Shift+Q, Q). Then click the "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator".

You can see some view attributes there as well as the way it's build up.

There's also a hierarchy viewer in the SDK tools/ directory, but I haven't used it yet.

[image: devices view]

Comment: For Android Studio: pull-down menu > Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor.